# Should connect system call succeed over https / port 443

Tags: linux, sockets, ssl, client-certificates, rhodes

I'm using an old cross platform mobile platform (Rhomobile) which supports an api call to detect if there is an available network connection. The source code is available and I can see when we do a call to detect connection we examine the results of the OS level system call to make a socket connection for a given url and port. This was working fine previously as our endpoint was http. We have now migrated this to https and are seeing some strange results. Call made will be

```
    struct addrinfo hints, *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL;
    int sockfd = -1;
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    char szPortAsString[5 + 1];
    snprintf(szPortAsString,5,"%d",m_iPort);
    char* szHost = new char[m_szHost.length() + 1];
    memset(szHost, 0, m_szHost.length() + 1);
    strcpy(szHost, m_szHost.c_str());
    int iResult = getaddrinfo(szHost, szPortAsString, &hints, &result);
    ...
    sockfd = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
    ...
    connect(sockfd, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen);
```

and the port will be 443. What I was unclear about whether the connection will be accepted (we don't need to pass any data) across to an https endpoint which **requires a client certificate** to send/receive data.

Code can be found here: https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/blob/3f5cf6ffa90cf8c648ac19c954932d101fc56b42/lib/commonAPI/coreapi/ext/platform/android/jni/NetworkDetect.cpp

Comment: What's wrong with just calling `getaddrinfo( m_szHost.c_str(), ... );`?  All that `new char[]`; strcpy(), and hopefully a later `delete` are completely unnecessary.  And don't post just links to code:  ["also include the code in your question itself"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This code is in the framework, so I'm not planning on changing it. Question is whether or not the connect will succeed against https without the client certificate being presented

Comment: SSL/TLS (and HTTPS) is not done at socket level, only TCP and IP is. **Socket connect() to 443 succeeds or fails in the same fashion as any other TCP connection;** if and after it succeeds some library like OpenSSL GnuTLS NSS etc. then implements SSL/TLS over the socket (using TCP) which may (as in your case) include client authentication using a certificate, and then HTTP on top of that giving HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 that was my understanding too, but it's not my area so was hoping to get that clarification. As the service is just a poll to see whether we have an active connection this should work well for http or https

Comment: If you want to make this the answer, perhaps with a reference I'd be happy to accept it.